# How to merge several video files into a single file with effects?

Tags: windows-phone-8, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I'm using `Windows Azure Media Services` to upload videos, I want to know if there is a way to **merge several video files into a single file**.

If it's impossible, which the best API for video merge effects, I already sent a request to get access to **Animoto** API, but still no response.

Answer (score 1):

WAMS does not offer that feature/functionality.

You can do that sort of thing with many tools prior to upload, this is considered video editing.
Wams offers a range of platform services: secure uploading, encoding, encryption, streaming, adaptive streaming, dynamic transmuxing, secure egress, with many more features to come.

But video editing is not on the roadmap.

Comment: Thanks, I think the solution is to make a Movie Maker Project on a Server and use it from a Command Line...

Comment: Here is one solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182568/using-movie-maker-programmatically-or-from-command-line