# Using Movie Maker programmatically or from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, movie

Does anyone know if I can programmatically hook into Movie Maker and therefore make a movie through an API or other form of command line ?

I found this [Command-line Options for Windows Movie Maker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb404142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but there is no **export** command to export the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one would be the official API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb288384(v=vs.85).aspx
However I found nothing on exporting either.

http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page Looks like a powerful alternative though (my guess is you don't mind being stuck on windows anyway in this case).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing some programming and have Windows 7 or later you can use Microsoft Media Foundation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819476(v=vs.85).aspx